# This IE and IE6 hack with only CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #botonHome .contButton p a span{ height:25px; }
        #botonHome .contButton p a span input{ position: relative; bottom:5px; }
    </style>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #botonHome .contButton p a span input{ display: inline; margin:0px; padding:0px; bottom:0px; height:20px; }                                       
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Finally I was able to display properly a button in all browsers, but I would like not to use this inline code in my html file. How can I solve this different CSS implementations for IE using only CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to trick IE6 just put "_" before any property, for example

```
   #botonHome .contButton p a span input{  _display: inline; _margin:0px; _padding:0px; _bottom:0px; _height:20px; }
```

UPDATE:

follow this link for [css IE hacks](http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please follow the link, you will find all you need about this topic, including detailed answer to your question

Comment: happy to hear this. if it solved your problem please mark the answer :)

Comment: i was about to, but I had to wait few minutes; you got it!

Comment: @mkk let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2271/discussion-between-toni-michel-caubet-and-mkk)

Answer (score 3):

For IE 6 use `_` underscore symbol before each style, for IE 7 Use `*` star symbol before each style and for IE8 & IE9 use `\0/` before closing the style with`;` semicolon symbol. See below for the code.

```
#botonHome .contButton p a span input {  

    /*For IE 6*/
    _display: inline; 
    _margin:0px; 
    _padding:0px; 
    _bottom:0px; 
    _height:20px;

     /*For IE 7*/

    *display: inline; 
    *margin:0px; 
    *padding:0px; 
    *bottom:0px; 
    *height:20px; 

    /*For IE 8 & 9*/

    display: inline\0/; 
    margin:0px\0/; 
    padding:0px\0/; 
    bottom:0px\0/; 
    height:20px\0/;
 }
```

Comment: Disadvantage is that your css won't validate, possibly introducing future problems, while with conditional comment, you are sure that your hacks are only included in the browsers that need them.

Answer (score 1):

These conditional comments are very handy for IE workarounds. I would use them, but not to include the style element, but to include a css file instead. That way, you don't have to add the entire style to each page, and you are able to add other tweaks more easily.