# Button Inconsistency in IE7 with padding

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I have managed to improve `button` element consistency somewhat with CSS, but IE7 is still misbehaving. Button width is 2px greater in IE7 and button height is 4px greater in IE7.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJQN2/2/ using IE7

All other browsers seem to be consistent.

How can I fix this, it is the height that is causing me the grief!

Answer (score 0):

you can use hack and add special css property that will work only with ie:

```
 *+html .yourDiv{height: XXpx;}
```

Just use 4px lower value if this is causing the problem

if you are more interested into hacks for IE, consider visiting this link with [css hacks for IE](http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/), which I have already given as answer for [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995245/this-ie-and-ie6-hack-with-only-css/6995258#6995258)

Comment: ohw, this is a terrible suggestion. If anything Conditional Comments are the better way to target older IE versions. The hacks you suggest always seem to bite back after a little while, and are a hell for maintainability. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: @mkk I want to avoid defining a specific button height for various reasons. I am happy to include ie7.css (by PHP detection), but I need to force IE7 to fall inline with every other browser. I cannot go introducing heights for all browsers just to please IE7.

Comment: @Bazzz: I agree, everything is written inside the link.